# Update table column with the same table column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to update 6 columns with another column's values in same table. And I want to do this by using a stored procedure where I want to pass two parameters

1. table name
2. param values

In this param I have the column list which I want to update so please let me know how could I achieve this.

eg: I have a column `startdate` which is of type `int64` and another column is `startdatetime` of type `datetime`. So I want to copy the date of `startdate` to `startdatetime` and there are around 5 columns in my table which I want to do the same for another.

Comment: Please share table schema.

Comment: Nice, but what is the problem :D

Comment: so please share some ideas

Comment: i mean just swapping the value of multiple column of table.so i need some idea for that how i achieve this with store procedure

Comment: As soon as you want to pass around table or column names as parameters, you have to resort to dynamic SQL....